# how to make my amazon-connect instance multi-region or multi-AZ?

Tags: amazon-connect

please I have amazon-connect instances in a specific region, and I want to implement failover, like I wanna make my amazon-connect instances multi-region or multi-AZ , so that if the primary region failed , the secondary  instances from the other region can pick-up the workload easily without downtime?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything, Amazon takes care of Connect resiliancy as part of the service. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/reliability-bp.html

Update: Looks like after a major outage a while back in us-west-2 Amazon have added cross region resiliancy. See the answer from @KPaxton below.

Note that this feature is available only for Amazon Connect instances created in the US East (N. Virginia) and US West (Oregon) Regions.

Comment: you didn't understand my question

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Connect Global Resiliency provides a set of APIs that you use to:

```
Provision a linked Amazon Connect instance in another AWS Region.

Provision and manage phone numbers that are global and accessible in both Regions.

Distribute telephony traffic between the instances and across Regions in 10% increments.

For example, you can distribute traffic 100% in US East (N. Virginia) / 0% in US West (Oregon), or 50% in each Region.

Access reserved capacity across Regions.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/setup-connect-global-resiliency.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).